# How to solve "Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor" in autoencoder Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am working on an Encoder and want to implement a skip conection. As shown in the code below it's denoted as `x1`:

The imports:

````
try:
  # Use the %tensorflow_version magic if in colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass

import tensorflow as tf



import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging
import os
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, add
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard # ??


from glob import glob

#IMPORTSSSS
import imageio
import skimage
from skimage import color
from skimage import transform
import pathlib
import cv2
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


#eager tensor
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()


%tensorflow_version 2.x
! nvidia-smi



from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
(trainX, testX, _, _) = train_test_split(data, data, test_size=0.20, random_state=None)


trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, axis=-1)
testX = np.expand_dims(testX, axis=-1)
trainX = trainX.astype("float32") / 255.0
testX = testX.astype("float32") / 255.0


filters=(256, 128, 64, 32)
latentDim=2048
EPOCHS =64 
BS = 16



def AE_V2_Model(filters, latentDim): 


        HEIGHT = 28 ##80#
        WIDTH = 28 #320#
        width =WIDTH
        height = HEIGHT

        padding_="same"
        depth=1

        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        # define the input to the encoder
        input_img = Input(shape=inputShape)
        #print( input_img.shape)


        x = Conv2D(filters[0], (3, 3), padding='same')(input_img)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        #print(x.shape)

        ############################################################################
        x = Conv2D(filters[1], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        ############################################################################


        x1 = Conv2D(filters[2], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x1)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        #print(x.shape)

        x = Conv2D(filters[3], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

        # flatten the network and then construct our latent vector
        volumeSize = K.int_shape(encoded)
        x = Flatten()(encoded)
        #print(x.shape)
        latent = Dense(latentDim)(x)
        #print(latent.shape)
        # build the encoder model
        encoder = Model(input_img, latent, name="encoder")

        # start building the decoder model which will accept the
        # output of the encoder as its inputs
        latentInputs = Input(shape=(latentDim,))
        x = Dense(np.prod(volumeSize[1:]))(latentInputs)
        x = Reshape((volumeSize[1], volumeSize[2], volumeSize[3]))(x)  # becomes like encoded 2D
        #print(x.shape)


        ############################################################################
        x = Conv2D(filters[3], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        ############################################################################



        x = Conv2D(filters[2], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        #print(x.shape)


        x=add([x,x1])


        x = Conv2D(filters[1], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        #print(x.shape)


        x = Conv2D(filters[0], (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        #print(x.shape)


        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        x = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        decoded = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
        # build the decoder model
        decoder = Model([input_img, latentInputs], decoded, name="decoder")
        # our autoencoder is the encoder + decoder
        autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoder([input_img, encoder(input_img)]),name="autoencoder")
        return encoder, decoder, autoencoder



%reload_ext tensorboard

from datetime import datetime

pathTensorBoard= "..."

log_dir = pathTensorBoard+ nameOfTheModel +datetime.now().strftime("res_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
  
#%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=log_dir

opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)   # to test adamax optimizer too
autoencoder.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt) # loss function is to be tested with few posibilities    loss='mse'


tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

  H = autoencoder.fit(
      trainX, trainX,
      validation_data=(testX, testX),
      epochs=EPOCHS,
      batch_size=BS,
      callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


  encoder.save(savingPath+nameOfTheModel+' - encoder - SC.h5')
  decoder.save(savingPath+nameOfTheModel+' - decoder - SC.h5')
  autoencoder.save(savingPath+nameOfTheModel+' - autoencoder - SC.h5')





```

My problem is I get the error below and I don't know why.

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
        (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_16' with dtype float and shape [?,1024]
        [[{{node input_16}}]]
        [[Func/training_2/Adam/gradients/gradients/decoder_6/batch_normalization_68/cond_grad/StatelessIf/else/_4397/input/_11045/_2875]]
        (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_16' with dtype float and shape [?,1024]
        [[{{node input_16}}]]
      0 successful operations.
      0 derived errors ignored.


```
````

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing a full example. Can you please show a minimal reproducible example of your data and the exact setup you ran that produced this error? All I see is the function and the error message. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @TCArlen .  I am actually trying to impelement a AE on MNIST dataset . I will add the full code.

Comment: Thanks for adding! But what is `data` it is not defined. Is that MNIST?

Comment: yes it's MNIST dataset